# Unable to open software-center in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-center, python

When I click on Ubuntu Software Center it does nothing. Would you please help to get it working?

Also I tried update & upgrade, but no use. I tried it via terminal using software-center then it gives this error.

```
abdul@abdul-Lenovo-G580:~/git/Flex-Voicemail/voicemail$ software-center
2013-07-10 08:44:15,044 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-07-10 08:44:15,088 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger:         '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2013-07-10 08:44:15,088 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on  com.ubuntu.sso:/com/ubuntu/sso/credentials: dbus.exceptions.DBusException:  org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu- sso-login exited with status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 338, in  __init__
self.icons)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 141, in find_oauth_token_sync
sso.find_credentials()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 75, in find_credentials
self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
**keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process   /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1
```

Comment: Please run `software-center` from the terminal and post any errors.  Thanks.

Comment: @Seth: i just edited my question please check.

Answer (score 1):

i have installed a Zope module from some other source than the official repository, to fix this i run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1085425

now it works for me. :D